# How to write formula in xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, formula, xlsxwriter

I have an excel that is being created with xlsxwriter in Python and I want to add another column that will be a formula that will divide two cells. The picture below represents what I'm trying to do (Column K):
[image]

And I have the following line of code but I don't know what else to write:

```
worksheet.write_formula(row+sigrowprecons,col+10,"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
worksheet.write_array_formula('K2:K100', '{=I2:I100/J2:J100}', cell_format, 15)
```